# How to reference a node with a string?

Tags: swift, string, type-conversion, skspritenode

I have an array of nodes, each of their names are corresponding to a coordinate:

```
var x1y1 = SKSpriteNode()
var x2y1 = SKSpriteNode()
var x3y1 = SKSpriteNode()
var x1y2 = SKSpriteNode()
var x2y2 = SKSpriteNode()
var x3y2 = SKSpriteNode()
var x1y3 = SKSpriteNode()
var x2y3 = SKSpriteNode()
var x3y3 = SKSpriteNode()
```

I want to make a function for when a value is increased, it changes a specific node.

For Example: I have a variable called "xval" and it has a random value of 1-3. I want that xval to determine which node is changed.

Kinda like this:

```
"x\(xval)y2".color = .red
```

But how do I actually do this in a way that works?

Comment: Create a "Matrix" type, which stores an `Array<Array<SKSpriteNode>>`. I strongly recommend you read the Swift language guide, to cover the fundamentals like this. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html

Comment: @HikaruWatanabe Is it? I don't notice any resemblance at all.